# MongoDB, insert many only if no match

Tags: mongodb

I'm making a token system along with a payment rule.

I need an idempotent rule that will generate some token for user (One for each token he bought)

So i have the following token

```
{
  _id?: ObjectId;
  owner: ObjectId;
  type: string;
  origin: {
    paymentIntentId: string;
    date: Date;
  }
}
```

It can exists multiple tokens for one `paymentIntentId` but if multiple call try to create token for the same token (let's say 4) for one paymentIntentId that already own token, i would like to prevent or do a no-op.

How can i proceed ?

I'm having concurrency issue with prevent me to first query then update because the A check appears before the B insert.

Best regards

Comment: You could use a unique index to guarantee that you won't have duplicates. You can also use either `replaceOne` or `updateOne` with `upsert: true` to upsert documents only if they're not found

Comment: Yeah, I switched to an compound index with paymentIntentId + another numeric field which is the token number of the serie. Thanks :)